# .net image editor control

Tags: c#, .net, controls, image-manipulation

I am looking for a .net control that allows for the editing of images. The following features would be desirable:

- Crop
- Zoom
- Pen
- Line
- Brush
- Circle
- Polygon
- Full undo / redo
- Measure Tool
- Layers(not critical)

This control can either be Winforms or WPF, but would need to be extensible.

I am happy for it to be a commecial control or open source. If source code is also available C# is desired.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up finding that an "Image annotation" control satisfied all of my needs.

I went with [VintaSoftAnnotation.NET Plug-in](http://www.vintasoft.com/vsannotation-dotnet-index.html)

In my research I found others:

- leadtools
- atalasoft dotimage
- accusoft imagegear

Comment: I've been using the Atalasoft DotImage control. It works pretty well

Answer (score 1):

This would help :

[http://xtractpro.com/articles/Image-Editor.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20100715212312/http://xtractpro.com/articles/Image-Editor.aspx)

(Original website disappeared; updated link to use archive.org)

Comment: That image editor artical is quite good, though I'm hoping to find a control with a few more features. It look like you accidently posted the first link twice at the bottom.

Comment: @Aaron You can not find a free control witch do it for you. you can look for a commercial component for it, but finding it will be hard

Comment: Paying for a commercial component is not a problem, but yes I haven't found anything comercial or free in my searches so far.