# C# Windows Forms Application Image Cropping

Tags: c#, .net, image, winforms, crop

I'm trying to implement a windows application (.NET Framework C#, Windows Forms), in which I can load an image file and crop a region of this file.

I started to try this using a PictureBox.

I took this tutorial and customized it: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30725/Cropping-Images
but I ran into some problems with large images and zoom, also it's not the solution I imagined...

So I'm wondering if there is no library or framework which provides a ready to use UI Element for image manipulation?

Or is there a possibility to integrate some 3rd party software?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Comment: please show us your code or maybe a jsfiddle so we can help

Comment: Thank you, my code is almost as in the tutorial. But I think this would be too much effort to implement this myself (according to my ideas) so I'm searching for a ready solution.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878380/net-image-editor-control